# Get Y coordinate of top and bottom of ImageView

Tags: android, coordinates, translation, android-sensors

I have an image view which is contained within a relative layout.  I am trying to get the screen y coordinates of the top of the image view and the screen y coordinates of the bottom of the image view.  I have tried this:

```
 float yMin = (float)levelH.getTop();
 float yMax = (float)levelH.getBottom();
```

float yMin seems almost correct.  I am translating another image view (IM2) up and down this image view(IM1).  So I am trying to set a limit on how far (IM2) can translate up and down.  So my thinking was to get the y top and bottom of (IM1) I can set those as max and min.

Anyone know how to do this?

ps Im using android accelometer to move (IM2)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`getTop()` ansd `getBottom()` look at coordinates within it's parent. To get coordinates of it's position on the screen you can use `getLocationOnScreen`

Use it like this:

```
int[] coords = {0,0};
view.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
int absoluteTop = coords[1];
int absoluteBottom = coords[1] + view.getHeight();
```

Comment: thanks for that.  I'll get on it straight away.  Looking at that now, it seems so logical, thanks again, I'll let you know how it goes and accept if I get it right

Comment: that doesn't seem to work unfortunately...I get the top and bottom as above but it just doesn't seem to work.  If I want to set the position of of IM2, so if IM2 is less that absolute top set IM2 y coordinate to absolutetop.  I had IM2.setY(absoluteTop).  Is this right?

Comment: int[] posXY = {0,0};    indicator.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);  int yPos = posXY[1] - (indicatorHeight/2);   int absoluteTop = coords[1];
            int absoluteBottom = coords[1] + levelBar.getHeight();  if(yPos<=absoluteTop) indicator.setY(absoluteTop);
            if(yPos>=absoluteBottom) indicator.setY(absoluteBottom);    That's my logic, does it look correct?

Comment: I have tried this and it does set the indicator (IM2) to the top but the app crashes saying the child already has parent view and I need to remove the view      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            lp.topMargin = 0;  if(yPos<=absoluteTop) levelH.addView(indicator, lp);

Comment: if anyone could shine some light on this I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Use View.getLocationOnScreen() and/or getLocationInWindow()

Comment: That isn't really what I'm looking for, surely that will only provide me with the center x,y of the image view?

Comment: thanks, I already knew those methods, I'm asking because I don't know and I've researched and I still don't know.

Comment: You can use the methods above with combination with your view width and height. You can also try this: ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Rect rect = iv.getDrawable().getRect();
int xOffset = rect.left;
int yOffset = rect.top;

Comment: might this work?  ' Rect r = levelBar.getDrawable().getBounds();

            int TopY = r.top;
            int BottomY = r.bottom;'